# Canvas not filling up div

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I need a canvas as a background for a div, so I put one that overlaps it. However, it isn't filling up the whole thing. I tried setting the left, right, top and bottom, and making the margin and padding 0, but it isn't working. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/vhsdLncu/24/).
CSS:

```
body {
     background: white;
     padding: 20px;
     font-family: Helvetica;
     height:100%;
}
 #editor_contentwrapper{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background: #353535;
     position: absolute;
     height:100%;
     width:70%;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     padding-top:30px;
}
 #editor_settings{
     background: gray;
     position: absolute;
     height:100%;
     width:30%;
     left:70%;
     top:0px;
}
 #editor_editor{
     background: white;
     width:90%;
     min-width:400px;
     min-height:100%;
     margin:auto;
}
 #editor_canv{
     position:relative;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     background:red;
     width:100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id=editor_contentwrapper>
   <div id=editor_editor>
      <canvas id=editor_canv></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
<div id=editor_settings></div>
```

Comment: Do you need the canvas to resize as the div is resized too?

Comment: Yes, the canvas should be the same size and location as the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in order to make the child element the same height as the parent element using just css, you would have to change the css a little, like so:

```
#editor_editor{
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width:90%;
  min-width:400px;
  min-height:100%;
  margin:auto;
}
#editor_canv{
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So the parent element, in this case #editor_editor would have its position as relative and the child would have position absolute. Putting the height at 100% for the child element, #editor_canv, will resize to the parent. Here is the js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vhsdLncu/35/. Here is a tutorial on this if you would like to see more infomation: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/
Hope that helps!